# Probability Questions binomials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> A defence system is $99.5\%$ efficient in intercepting ballistic missiles.  (a) How many missiles must an aggressor launch to have a better than evens chance of one or more penetrating the defenses?

May you please show some steps to help me solve this?
Thank you

Comment: You’re not looking for _exactly one_ missile to get through, but one _or more_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the missiles to represent (independent) Bernoulli trials, the binomial distribution is applicable (since the failure rate $0.005$ is so low, we could approximate this with the Poisson distribution for large $n$).

The probability of $k$ missiles out of $n$ penetrating the defence system is:

$$p(k,n)=\binom{n}{k}(0.005)^k(0.995)^{n-k}$$

For $k=0$ this reduces to

$$p(0,n)=0.995^{n}$$

Hence we are looking for the smallest $n$ for which $0.995^n<0.5$. Then

$$0.995^n=0.5 \implies n\ln(0.995)=\ln(0.5) \implies n=\frac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(0.995)}\approx138.3$$

So $n=139$ guarantees a better than even chance that at least one missile will get through.