# A defence system is 99.5% efficient in intercepting ballistic missiles.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, poissons-equation

how many missiles would be needed to ensure a better than evens chance of more than two missiles evading the defenses?

I got: $1 - 0.995^n - \left[(0.005^n) \times (0.995^{n-1}) \times n\right] - \left[(0.005^2) \times (0.995^{n-2})\times \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right] = \frac{1}{2}$

when compute numerically I got 263 from wolfram whilst the book says 535

Comment: I edited your question. Please check if it is correct.

Comment: looks better thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability Questions binomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469006/probability-questions-binomials)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote $(.005^n)$. You should have written $(.005^1)$. If you try solving it again, you should get the right answer. Based on the rest of your work, it seems like you know what you're doing, and this was just a typo.